# Cloudera 5 - oozie PoolableConnectionFactory

Tags: cloudera, oozie, openjpa

I have installed the cloudera 5 manager and now i'm trying to use it following this example https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example.

Starting the data pipeline, logs shows:

SERVER[xxxx] Runtime Exception during Services Load. Check your list of 'oozie.services' or 'oozie.services.ext'

SERVER[xxxx] E0103: Could not load service classes, Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure
org.apache.oozie.service.ServiceException: E0103: Could not load service classes, Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

Caused by:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

any ideas?I can´t see the error..

Thanks in advance.

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/etc/oozie/conf.dist/oozie-default.xml

```
    <property>
        <name>oozie.base.url</name>
        <value>http://localhost:8080/oozie</value>
        <description>
             Base Oozie URL.
        </description>
    </property>
<!-- DB Schema Info, used by DBLiteWorkflowStoreService -->
    <property>
        <name>oozie.db.schema.name</name>
        <value>oozie</value>
        <description>
            Oozie DataBase Name
        </description>
    </property>
<!-- StoreService -->
    <property>
        <name>oozie.service.JPAService.create.db.schema</name>
<!-- DB Schema Info, used by DBLiteWorkflowStoreService -->
    <property>
        <name>oozie.db.schema.name</name>
        <value>oozie</value>
        <description>
            Oozie DataBase Name
        </description>
    </property>
   <!-- StoreService -->
    <property>
        <name>oozie.service.JPAService.create.db.schema</name>
         <value>false</value>
        <description>
            Creates Oozie DB.
            If set to true, it creates the DB schema if it does not exist. If the DB schema exists is a NOP.
            If set to false, it does not create the DB schema. If the DB schema does not exist it fails start$
        </description>
    </property>
```

Every time I restart CDH5 a folder is created in /run/cloudera-scm-agent/process, this is correct?

/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/459-oozie-OOZIE_SERVER/oozie-site.xml

```
    <property>
        <name>oozie.service.JPAService.jdbc.driver</name>
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>oozie.service.JPAService.jdbc.username</name>
        <value>oozie_oozie_server</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>oozie.service.JPAService.jdbc.password</name>
        <value>********</value>
    </property>
I don't know the password
    <property>
        <name>oozie.service.JPAService.jdbc.url</name>
        <value>jdbc:mysql://xxxxxx:7432/oozie_oozie_server?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>oozie.base.url</name>
        <value>http://xxxxxxx:11000/oozie</value>
      </property>
      <property>
```

This url doesn't work (unavailable or too busy).

JDBC driver for MySQL/openJPA

```
/usr/share/cmf/common_jars/openjpa-persistence-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/usr/share/cmf/common_jars/openjpa-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/usr/share/cmf/cloudera-navigator-server/libs/cdh5/openjpa-persistence-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/usr/share/cmf/cloudera-navigator-server/libs/cdh5/openjpa-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/oozie/libtools/openjpa-persistence-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/oozie/libtools/openjpa-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/oozie/libtools/openjpa-persistence-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/oozie/libtools/openjpa-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/jars/openjpa-persistence-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/jars/openjpa-jdbc-2.2.2.jar


/usr/share/cmf/common_jars/openjpa-persistence-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/usr/share/cmf/common_jars/openjpa-persistence-2.2.2.jar
/usr/share/cmf/common_jars/openjpa-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/usr/share/cmf/common_jars/openjpa-lib-2.2.2.jar
/usr/share/cmf/common_jars/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
/usr/share/cmf/common_jars/openjpa-kernel-2.2.2.jar
/usr/share/cmf/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
/usr/share/cmf/cloudera-navigator-server/libs/cdh5/openjpa-persistence-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/usr/share/cmf/cloudera-navigator-server/libs/cdh5/openjpa-persistence-2.2.2.jar
/usr/share/cmf/cloudera-navigator-server/libs/cdh5/openjpa-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/usr/share/cmf/cloudera-navigator-server/libs/cdh5/openjpa-lib-2.2.2.jar
/usr/share/cmf/cloudera-navigator-server/libs/cdh5/openjpa-kernel-2.2.2.jar
/usr/share/cmf/cloudera-navigator-server/jars/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/oozie/libtools/openjpa-persistence-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/oozie/libtools/openjpa-persistence-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/oozie/libtools/openjpa-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/oozie/libtools/openjpa-lib-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/oozie/libtools/openjpa-kernel-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/oozie/libserver/openjpa-persistence-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/oozie/libserver/openjpa-persistence-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/oozie/libserver/openjpa-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/oozie/libserver/openjpa-lib-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/oozie/libserver/openjpa-kernel-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/jars/openjpa-persistence-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/jars/openjpa-persistence-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/jars/openjpa-jdbc-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/jars/openjpa-lib-2.2.2.jar
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/jars/openjpa-kernel-2.2.2.jar
```

Comment: 'oozie.services' or 'oozie.services.ext' properties are configured into oozie-default.xml and oozie-site.xml. Please check.

Comment: Nobody can help me?